# tag merge request: [actor] & [actor-model]

Tags: support, retag-request

[actor-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actor-model) should be merged into [actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actor) which seems to be the defacto standard.

There is no tag wiki for actor-model and it only has 23 questions.  There are over 1100 questions for the actor tag, although there may be some ambiguity on that tag.

Comment: Better call Zoolander.